# Embedding FlutterFlow app with react - Query parameters doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, flutter, interop, flutterflow, dart-js-interop

I am trying to embed Flutterflow app in a React app which uses certain query parameters, I am getting errors while trying to render Flutter widgets as React components. Its working fine when there are no query parameters eg. xyz.com/ but doesn't work when its xyz.com?qp=123

This is the exact error i am getting:

```
ERROR

Exception: The base href has to end with a "/" to work correctly 
Exception: The base href has to end with a "/" to work correctly at Object.f 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:4974:19) at Object.ae 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:4983:15) at http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:9006:20 at aKV.a 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:6303:63) at aKV.$2 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:40625:14) at Object.R 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:6289:10) at Object.aLH 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:9033:10) at aLJ.$0 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:81607:15) at http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:44865:12 at aKV.a 
(http://localhost:3000/flutter/main.dart.js:6303:63)
```

Note: When I am embedding a normal flutter app using the same method, its working fine but this is happening specifically with flutterflow apps.

How I am trying to embed?

This is my prebuild npm script:

```
"prebuild": "cd embedding_test && flutter clean && flutter build web --output=../public/flutter && cd -",
```

I have placed the app created by flutterflow at the root of my react app, then ran this command. The component that reads the `main.dart.js` and renders the app has the logic as below:

```
export const FlutterView: React.FC<FlutterViewProps> = memo(
  ({
    assetBase = "",
    src = "main.dart.js",
    onClicksChange,
    onScreenChange,
    onTextChange,
    text,
    screen,
    clicks,
  }) => {
    const flutterState = useRef<any>(null);
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const onFlutterAppLoaded = (state: any) => {
      flutterState.current = state;
      // listen to state changes
      state.onClicksChanged(onClicksChange);
      state.onTextChanged(onTextChange);
      state.onScreenChanged(onScreenChange);
      // set initial values
      state.setText(text);
      state.setScreen(screen);
      state.setClicks(clicks);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const target = ref.current;
      let isRendered = true;
      const initFlutterApp = async () => {
        if (!isRendered) return;
        const engineInitializer = await new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
          _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
            entrypointUrl: src,
            onEntrypointLoaded: resolve,
          });
        });
        if (!isRendered) return;

        const appRunner = await engineInitializer?.initializeEngine({
          hostElement: target,
          assetBase: assetBase,
        });
        if (!isRendered) return;

        await appRunner?.runApp();
      };
      initFlutterApp();

      const eventListener = (event: Event) => {
        let state = (event as CustomEvent).detail;
        onFlutterAppLoaded(state);
      };

      target?.addEventListener("flutter-initialized", eventListener, {
        once: true,
      });

      return () => {
        isRendered = false;
        target?.removeEventListener("flutter-initialized", eventListener);
      };
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      flutterState.current?.setText(text);
    }, [text]);
    useEffect(() => {
      flutterState.current?.setScreen(screen);
    }, [screen]);
    useEffect(() => {
      flutterState.current?.setClicks(clicks);
    }, [clicks]);

    return (
      <div className="flutter-view" ref={ref} style={divStyle}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            height: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <CircularProgress />
        </Box>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```